# SQL SYSDATETIME and SYSUTCDATETIME

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the SQL Server date time and my local datetime.

Assume my current time is 3.47 pm.

Now I'm using SQL Server Management Studio which is installed in my local machine. And When I execute following commands it returns two different values.But Its OK since `SYSDATETIME` 'll return server datetime and 
`SYSUTCDATETIME` 'll return local datetime.

```
SELECT SYSDATETIME()
SELECT SYSUTCDATETIME()
```

Return Values are

> 2015-07-23 12:17:03.2686085

And

> 2015-07-23 10:17:03.2686085

But the problem is the value I'm getting from `SYSUTCDATETIME` is not equal to my local datetime.

How can that happen?

Comment: *`SYSUTCDATETIME` 'll return local datetime.* - nope, it will return the UTC date and time which is different from local datetime

Comment: Then How can I get my local datetime

Comment: use `SWITCHOFFSET` or `TODATETIMEOFFSET` based on your exact requirement. `SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),'+01:00')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can get with the help of 
[image]

```
TODATETIMEOFFSET ( expression , time_zone )
```

for more detail
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb630335.aspx

my systeme time is [image]
and when i run query

```
SELECT SYSDATETIME()
    ,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
    ,SYSUTCDATETIME()
    ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ,GETDATE()
    ,GETUTCDATE();
```

i got below result
[image]