# SQL Server 2016's "at time zone" function not working as expected

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, datetime, momentjs

I'm using SQL Server 2016 at Amazon AWS. My emails are being sent with incorrect times when sent from my pupper at Amazon. When I try to recreate this bug locally the times are correct. Here is an example of how I use `at time zone`.

`getDate() at time zone 'utc' at time zone u.timezone`

where `u.timezone` is the user's timezone and `u` refers to an aliased table `users`.

The times being outputted are at UTC time, so I see `7:36pm` instead of `2:36pm` (they are formatted with MomentJS)

I don't really know where to start with this one, sorry guys and gals.

**UPDATE**

My server is sending the correct time (with the correct timezone offset) to the email factory. When the server creates the emails, times are formatted using MomentJS. The barebones `moment()` function will take a time with a timezone offset (-5:00) and adjust it to the local machine's local time. Local time on my machine is EST, but in Amazon (where the email is being created) is not. Thus I must use `moment.parseZone()`.

From the [MomentJS docs](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/):

```
If your date format has a fixed timezone offset, use moment.parseZone:
moment.parseZone("2013-01-01T00:00:00-13:00");
This results in a date with a fixed offset:
"2013-01-01T00:00:00-13:00"
```

Since I can't see this change until it is pushed onto our dev environment, I won't be able to know if this fixed it, but I think this was the problem.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't use [`GETUTCDATE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178635.aspx) for the first part? How incorrect are the incorrect times? What time zone are you in?

Comment: Sorry I meant to include ouput in my post, I'll edit. There is no reason I can't use that. I try this.

Comment: Oh, I suppose your server instance might not be running in UTC, in which case one of the functions listed in [SQL SYSDATETIME and SYSUTCDATETIME](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31584658/1115360) will be suitable for your usage.

Comment: This was the realization that dawned on me when reading your comment, thank you!

Comment: I think that you could usefully create your own answer to this stating where it went wrong with regard to timezones and how you solved it :)

Comment: I updated the post. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My server was sending the correct time (with the correct timezone offset) to the email factory. When the server created the emails, times were formatted using MomentJS.

The barebones `moment()` function takes a time with a timezone offset (-5:00) and adjusts it to the local machine's local time.

Local time on my machine is EST, but in Amazon (where the email is being created) is not. Thus I must use `moment.parseZone()`.

Changing to `moment.parseZone()` fixed this issue. Problem solved.